# is there a difference in the way the icons are referenced in build and installer versions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, installation

is there a difference in the way the icons are referenced in build and installed version ?
When i build from Visual Studio , The form icon does not have any white  background , but after installation the form icon has a white background
All this while ,I was thinking in Installation the icons are picked from the exe, is that right ?

Comment: Icons are usually extracted from the exe. Usually, application controls the icon used for its window when window (form) is created. So it should use the same icon whether it was installed or it was just run after building. Check the icon in an icon editor to make sure it has _transparent_ pixels. More details would also be great: is this a window icon, is this an icon in UI?

Comment: ya i checked the icons with the photo editor and i see in few images say in just 8 bit images the icon have white background , in 32 bit its transparent . can you please advice me how to remove the white background from the 8 bit images? And Thanks for you comment above , did make me think abt the icons once

Comment: I converted my comment to an answer, and added info about editing. Just to clarify: Do you test the installed version over remote desktop or on a virtual machine? These the cases where the image quality can be reduced, and Windows selects 8 bit icon instead of 32 bit one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Icons are usually extracted from the exe. It is application that controls the icon used for its window when window (form) is created (and the icon can be changed during runtime). So it should use the same icon whether it was installed or it was just run after building.

Check the icon in an icon editor to make sure it has transparent pixels.
More details would also be great: is this a window icon, is this an icon in UI?

Update: You should use an icon editor to fill the background with transparent color. Visual Studio cannot edit 32 bit icons, but you can give it a try with editing that 8 bit one (make a backup copy in case VS spoils the 32 bit subimage). I used [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/) editor, it used to be free but now it's not.

Comment: hi , I realised that yesterday . And used real world icon editor to remove the white background and fill it with transparent colors . Yes i was testing with  remote machines and also virtual machines . as you said the white background was only there in 8 bit images . so i replaces the white with transparent background and replaced the images . Thanks for your hint to look at the images . this helped me a lot .